# Only allow access to S3 objects from website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is it possible to only allow access to images in an S3 bucket via a specific website?

I'm trying to prevent users from being able to access the image directly in the browser to prevent them from being able to download the images for free, but I need my website to be able to load them so they can see a preview.

I went through this tutorial step-by-step, but it still didn't work properly:
https://keithweaverca.medium.com/only-allowing-access-to-your-s3-bucket-via-your-website-5ca5c8546152

Answer (score 0):

If you want a preview feature you may need to consider saving 2 images

1. Public Image that is Pixilated / Watermarked
2. An authorized image with some authentication aolution like Cognito

Comment: If you are providing the 'preview' image to the web browser, then users can save the image. Basically, anything in the browser can be saved. Are you intending to provide them with a different 'preview image' than the actual image?